# How can I translate VB6 Recordset.FindFirst to C# while using an Access Database?

Tags: c#, ms-access, subquery, findfirst

I'm working on a project where I'm converting an old VB6 project to .NET/C#.  I've come upon a method that performs several queries, once of which uses the recordset.FindFirst method to generate sub-results.  I'm at a loss on how to translate this into C# without using LINQ (something I have no experience with anyway).  I've search through Google, etc and cannot find a relevant example that doesn't use LINQ.  Can anyone provide me with a simple C# example that executes a query, then executes a sub-clause against those results without using LINQ?

In my code I am using an `OldDbConnection` and an `OleDbReader` to query the table from the Access database.  Perhaps this is wrong?

Many thanks in advance for any examples you can provide.

Comment: Could you show your actual code?

Comment: I think you need to use the Select Method of a DataTable Object. It will probably be somewhat similar to ADO's Filter method, as the Select Method returns DataRow(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to load the initial query results into a `DataTable` and then use the `.Select` method to run the secondary query against the initial results. For example, for a table named [Users] in Access containing...

```
ID  UserName
--  --------
1   Jeff
2   Greg
3   Garth
4   Gord
5   Gary
6   Grant
7   Graham
```

...the following C# code...

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace oledbTest1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                conn.ConnectionString =
                        @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                        @"Data Source=C:\__tmp\testData.accdb;";
                conn.Open();
                using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandText =
                        "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID < 7 ORDER BY UserName";
                    var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    var dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    Console.WriteLine("The initial query from the Access database (WHERE ID < 7) returned:");
                    foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(dr["UserName"]);
                    }
                    System.Data.DataRow[] subsetRows;
                    subsetRows = dt.Select("UserName LIKE 'Gr%'");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("The equivalent of \".FindFirst UserName LIKE 'Gr%'\" on that subset would be:");
                    Console.WriteLine(subsetRows[0]["UserName"]);
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...produces the following result:

```
The initial query from the Access database (WHERE ID < 7) returned:
Garth
Gary
Gord
Grant
Greg
Jeff

The equivalent of ".FindFirst UserName LIKE 'Gr%'" on that subset would be:
Grant
```

Comment: Gord - this is fantastic, thank you.  I'm going to modify it to fit my implementation to see if it works.  I will post back quickly with my results.